# r-Error in knn: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)

Tags: python, r, twitter

I am analyzing the tweets by applying SVM, NB and kNN to know whether tweet is positive, negative or neutral, for this purpose I have 80704 tweets but for test purpose I am only analyzing only 2847 tweets, it has following features

```
> str(total.tweets.score)
'data.frame':   2847 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ score         : int  0 1 1 -2 0 0 1 2 -2 0 ...
 $ text          : Factor w/ 1790 levels "  st century is the era of knowledge and information which will change the way countries develop says",..: 1717 129 996 1072 682 795 524 132 143 773 ...
 $ Negative      : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
```

the question is when I divide the data into train and test data, It works for SVM and NB but gives the error when I apply kNN, here is how I splited data,

```
total.tweets.score.train <- total.tweets.score[1:1993,]
total.tweets.score.test  <- total.tweets.score[1994:2847, ]
```

SVM Model:

```
model.SVm = svm(total.tweets.score.train$Negative~., data = total.tweets.score.train, kernel = "linear", epsilon = 0.1, probability = TRUE, type = "C")
```

NB Model:

```
nb.classifier <- naiveBayes(twitter.train , total.tweets.score.train$Negative)
```

here `twitter.train` is document term matrix.

kNN Model:

```
model.knn <- knn(twitter.train, twitter.test , knn.train.data.target , k = 3, prob = TRUE)
```

here `twitter.train` and `twitter.test` both are document term matrix, while `kn.train.data.target` is factor

when I run kNN code, i receive following error,

```
Error in knn(twitter.train, twitter.test, knn.train.data.target, k = 3,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(twitter.train, twitter.test, knn.train.data.target, k = 3,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(twitter.train, twitter.test, knn.train.data.target, k = 3,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

please help me what to do?

Comment: What is the structure of your document term matrices? Could you post the structure and maybe a few rows? (This would be the only way to make your problem reproducible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of my DTM

```
> str(total.tweets.dtm)
List of 6
 $ i       : int [1:22041] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ j       : int [1:22041] 138 163 617 1417 1852 1899 2534 2727 2792 3234 ...
 $ v       : num [1:22041] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ nrow    : int 2847
 $ ncol    : int 4232
 $ dimnames:List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:2847] "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" "character(0)" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:4232] "#cpec" "aabpara" "aaj" "aakhir" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
 - attr(*, "weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
```